# Not unique table/alias: 'user' phpmyadmin XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I'm trying to connect my users from database into browser, running XAMPP. I select a user user from a list i created using the following code in my users_index.php file:

```
<div class="list-group">
<?foreach ($users as $user ):?>

    <a href="<?=BASE_URL?>users/view/<?=$user['username']?>" class="list-group-item"><?=$user['username']?></a>

<? endforeach?>
```

This works in accessing the DB and getting my usernames until i run my users_view.php file which contains a div:

```
<div>
    <span class="badge badge-success">By <?=$post["username"]?></span>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <?if(!empty($users)) foreach ($users [$post ['post_id']] as $user):?>
    <a href="#"><span class = "label" style="background-color: #5bc0de"><?=$user?></span></a>
    <?endforeach?>
</div>
```

After which i select the username from my list and it get this error message:

> Not unique table/alias: 'user'
>   In file C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\controllers\users.php, line 28, function view( )

When i go into that line this is what i have:

```
28: $user_id = get_one("SELECT user_id FROM user NATURAL JOIN user WHERE username='$username'");
```

I have a database running MySql and i use PMA to access it via browser. In the database i created 'user' table with the columns 'user_id', 'username', 'password' and 'deleted'.

My goal is: after i select a user from the list it should show posts made by that user.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't have a space between $post and ['post_id'] for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you are only asking for one table, so a join is irrelevant here - that's why there is an alias error - the database engine is expecting a second table.

For a join you need to make sure you're telling mysql the *relationship* between the tables.

For example:

```
SELECT user_id FROM user NATURAL JOIN user ON sometable.username = user.username WHERE user.username='$username'
```

So in this case, the related table is 'sometable.' Otherwise you'd just do a single table query:

```
SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE username='$username'
```

For what you are asking you would need two tables, one for your user information, and another for your 'posts made by user.'

The 'posts made by user' table would probably have a post_id (unique) and a user_id.

Comment: I tried using $user_id = get_one("SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE username='$username'"); and 
        $this->post = get_one("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username'"); Both got me a little closer. Now im getting the username from the table. I also have a 'post' table, which contains different columns like 'post_created', 'post_id', 'post_subject', 'post_text' and 'user_id'.

Comment: Ok, so you will select the user first to populate the list and store in a variable:

`SELECT username, user_id FROM user WHERE (whatever condition)`

Then do the join to list the posts in the second query:

`SELECT post_id, post_subject FROM post NATURAL JOIN user ON  post.userid = user.userid WHERE post.userid='$userid'`

In simpler terms - get the userid from the selected user first THEN find out what posts they've made.

Comment: I see what you mean. It worked in another 'tags' table i created but im still getting the error  `Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON post.user_id = user.user_id WHERE ''=post.user_id' ` while trying to connect to the post via post.user_id

Comment: Ah i think i had the WHERE statement the wring way around. Have edited.